# Binary Classification on MNIST in MatLab

Tags: matlab, binary, linear-algebra, mnist

How can I use the binary classifier to implement the one-vs-one and one-vs-all approach in MatLab? I have been trying to find a starting point somewhere and have struggled to find any resource to aid in the implementation. So far what I have is:

```
% Load MNIST training and testing data
load('mnist.mat');

% Extract features and labels
train_data = double(reshape(trainX, [], 784)) / 255.0; % Normalize to [0, 1]
train_labels = double(trainY);

test_data = double(reshape(testX, [], 784)) / 255.0; % Normalize to [0, 1]
test_labels = double(testY);

% Number of classes
K = 10;

% Number of features (pixels in this case)
D = size(train_data, 2);

% Binary least-squares classifier function
train_binary_classifier = @(X, y) pinv([ones(size(X, 1), 1) X]) * y;

% One-versus-all multi-class classifier
W_one_vs_all = zeros(D + 1, K);

for k = 1:K
    % Convert labels to binary (k vs all)
    binary_labels = (train_labels == k) * 2 - 1; % Convert to +1/-1
    
    % Train binary classifier for class k
    W_one_vs_all(:, k) = train_binary_classifier(train_data, binary_labels);
end

% One-versus-one multi-class classifier
W_one_vs_one = zeros(D + 1, D + 1, K*(K-1)/2);

index = 1;
for i = 1:K
    for j = i+1:K
        % Select only the samples with labels i and j
        binary_labels = (train_labels == i) | (train_labels == j);
        binary_data = train_data(binary_labels, :);
        binary_labels = double(train_labels(binary_labels) == i) * 2 - 1; % Convert to +1/-1
        
        % Train binary classifier for classes i and j
        W_one_vs_one(:, :, index) = train_binary_classifier(binary_data, binary_labels);
        
        index = index + 1;
    end
end

% Evaluate

% Function to predict labels using the trained classifier
predict_labels = @(X, W) sign([ones(size(X, 1), 1) X] * W);

% Evaluate one-versus-all classifier on training data
predicted_labels_one_vs_all = predict_labels(train_data, W_one_vs_all);
training_error_one_vs_all = sum(predicted_labels_one_vs_all ~= train_labels) / numel(train_labels);
confusion_matrix_one_vs_all = evaluate_confusion_matrix(train_labels, predicted_labels_one_vs_all, K);

disp(['One-versus-all Training Error: ', num2str(training_error_one_vs_all)]);
disp('One-versus-all Confusion Matrix:');
disp(confusion_matrix_one_vs_all);

% Evaluate one-versus-one classifier on training data
predicted_labels_one_vs_one = zeros(size(train_data, 1), 1);

for i = 1:K*(K-1)/2
    binary_labels = predict_labels(train_data, W_one_vs_one(:, :, i));
    predicted_labels_one_vs_one(binary_labels > 0) = i;
end

training_error_one_vs_one = sum(predicted_labels_one_vs_one ~= train_labels) / numel(train_labels);
confusion_matrix_one_vs_one = evaluate_confusion_matrix(train_labels, predicted_labels_one_vs_one, K);

disp(['One-versus-one Training Error: ', num2str(training_error_one_vs_one)]);
disp('One-versus-one Confusion Matrix:');
disp(confusion_matrix_one_vs_one);

% Function to evaluate the confusion matrix
function confusion_matrix = evaluate_confusion_matrix(true_labels, predicted_labels, num_classes)
    confusion_matrix = zeros(num_classes);

    for i = 1:num_classes
        true_positive = sum(true_labels == i & predicted_labels == i);
        false_positive = sum(true_labels ~= i & predicted_labels == i);
        true_negative = sum(true_labels ~= i & predicted_labels ~= i);
        false_negative = sum(true_labels == i & predicted_labels ~= i);

        confusion_matrix(i, :) = [true_positive, false_positive, true_negative, false_negative];
    end
end
```

I am currently getting the following error:

```
Error using  * 
Incorrect dimensions for matrix multiplication. Check that the number of columns in the first matrix matches the number of rows in the second matrix. To operate on each element of the
matrix individually, use TIMES (.*) for elementwise multiplication.

Error in Test4>@(X,y)pinv([ones(size(X,1),1),X])*y (line 18)
train_binary_classifier = @(X, y) pinv([ones(size(X, 1), 1) X]) * y;

Error in Test4 (line 28)
    W_one_vs_all(:, k) = train_binary_classifier(train_data, binary_labels);
```

I am not sure if the frame of the code is correct and am trying to debug this error to test

Comment: Are you expecting to do matrix multiplication or element-wise multiplication with `pinv([ones(size(X, 1), 1) X]) * y`? As the error states you're doing matrix multiplication with inputs of incompatible sizes - what size are you expecting the two multiplicand arrays to be?